# How can I debug what is being rendered to a Frame Buffer Object in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, debugging

I have a point cloud that is being rendered to the screen. Each point has its position and color as well as an ID.

I was asked to render the IDs for each point to a texture so I created a FBO and attached two textures, one for color and one for depth. I created the necessary VAO and VBO for this off-screen rendering and uploaded for each point its position and ID.

Once the rendering to the FBO is done, I read the pixels of the color-texture with `glReadPixels()` to see what the values are, but they seem to be all cleared out, i.e., the value they have is the same as `glClearColor()`.

Is there a way I can debug what it is being render to the color texture of my FBO? Any tips that you may provide are very welcomed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally to see what is being rendered in the various steps of your pipeline I'd suggest the use of a tool for frame analysis. These usually provide you with a view on the content of each buffer for each API call and this can help you in your situation.

A very good one is [Renderdoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc) which is both completely free and opensource. Also it is actively supported.

Another one is [Intel GPA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/gpa/details) that unfortunately, according to its webpage, support up to OGL 3.3 Core.

Just for the sake of adding one more, I used to use [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/), but it has passed long since the last update. This has evolved into [AMD CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/) that unfortunately I never used.

Comment: Additionally I also sometimes have a command that will dump a specified fbo out to an image when I press a key. It's the low-tech way.

Comment: It's also probably a good idea to make sure you have the right depth test setup, for the rendering going into your visualisation FBO.

Comment: I still use gDEbugger from time to time for older GL versions. CodeXL is the more modern version of it and can be found here: https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/CodeXL
Note that there's a comprehensive list of graphics debugging tools on the apitrace page here: https://apitrace.github.io/#links

Answer (score 11):

I tested several applications/APIs/libraries to get data from FBOs in applications which use gbuffer for example. After months of suffering I discovered [apitrace](https://apitrace.github.io/) available on Github to debug OpenGL, Direct3D and WebGL. I used in Windows and Linux without problems.

I hope that could be useful for you.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to cifz's response, another way to visualise FBOs which doesn't cost very much code is to use glBlitFramebuffer() to transfer pixels from a framebuffer to a window.

```
// XXX WARNING: Untested code follows

// Blit from fbo...
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
// ...to the front buffer.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_WRITE_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT);

GLsizei HalfWindowWidth = (GLsizei)(WindowWidth / 2.0f);
GLsizei HalfWindowHeight = (GLsizei)(WindowHeight / 2.0f);

// Blit attachment 0 to the lower-left quadrant of the window
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, FboWidth, FboHeight,
                  0, 0, HalfWindowWidth, HalfWindowHeight,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

// Blit attachment 1 to the lower-right quadrant of the window
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, FboWidth, FboHeight,
                  HalfWindowWidth, 0, WindowWidth, HalfWindowHeight,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

// ...and so on. You can switch FBOs if you have more than one to read from.
```

There are a few obvious "gotchas", in that HDR buffers probably won't visualise the way you expect them to, you probably can't "see" depth/stencil buffers in the obvious way, and if the size of the FBO doesn't match the area being blitted to, the magnification/minification method might be extremely naive.

But as quick 'n dirty hacks go, it's pretty good.