# GLSL shader debugging

Tags: opengl, glsl, debugging

Is there any tool available for debugging GLSL shaders?

I have nvidia geForce 940m GPU which doesn't support Nvidia NSight and RenderDoc is great but it doesn't support GLSL shader debugging. I am using windows 10.

Comment: You might want to say what platform you're on, as that will likely change the answer.

Comment: There's a list on the OpenGL page... https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debugging_Tools

Comment: Not sure about the quality of the various tools though, generally it's not up to the standard of the DirectX tools that ship with Visual Studio. I tried gDebugger on a project last year but it didn't work with compute shaders at all...

Comment: Questions about debugging GLSL are on topic. Questions like [this](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-can-i-debug-glsl-shaders) and [this](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-debug-what-is-being-rendered-to-a-frame-buffer-object-in-opengl) are fine. However, requests for off site resources (such as a debugging tool) are off topic here. You can ask for recommendations over on Software Recommendations but please read their [on topic](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page first.